# xcode - "attempt to use a deleted function" - what does that mean?

Tags: c++, xcode4.2, llvm-3.0

I am writing a C++ library in Xcode 4.2.

One of my classes won't compile with this error:

> attempt to use a deleted function

There is no specific indication what function it's talking about.
I don't want to post the class code here, but does anybody have any idea what this error means?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you've attempted to use (call or take the address of) a deleted function but if you don't want to post the code you're unlikely to be able to get much more help than is in the error message that you've posted.

Comment: Well , you've basically answered my question with my question. I know I've attempted to use a deleted function. The error told me that. but what is a deleted function?

Comment: That was my point. Without more context - the code - all that we can do is rephrase the error message. If you don't know what a deleted function is then ask that as a question.

Comment: I don't mean to troll, but as you can see the poster below has given me an answer which satisfied me. So I guess you could've given me one too..

Comment: Without more information you're question is not answerable, IMHO. I am happy that you are satisfied with the answer that you've been given. Why should I provide another answer? What am I supposed to put in it that you would benefit from? I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can declare functions as deleted:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
};
```

Attempting to use such a function is an error. The purpose of doing this is so that, in this example, copy construction of this type is not possible. This is a more direct replacement for the non-copyable trick used pre-C++11.

Also, there are rules in the C++ spec that lead to member functions being implicitly deleted.

The error is telling you that your program attempts to use a deleted function. You'll have to post the error you're getting for more detailed help.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar message with threads (C++11). It turned out that I was passing the wrong number of parameters to the function called by the thread so the thread did not find any function suitable and gave that message.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Carlos' answer, I had the right number of arguments but one of the arguments was being passed by reference. Adding ref() around the variable fixed it for me. See [here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Answer (score 1):

For me It solved it when I passed "this" pointer as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that one of the arguments was a pointer, and I passed NULL directly as an argument. To solve this, I simply created a new NULL pointer which I passed to the function as an l-value instead.