# Thread creation inside constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, pthreads

So, I am using C++11 and I made a class

```cpp
Class C
{
  private:
    queue<std::int> s;
    pthread_t x;
  public:
    C() {phthread_create(&x, NULL, d_q, NULL);
    void log(int p); // pushes into q.
    void* d_q(void* q); // this is a function which will pop s. assume s is thread safe.
}
```

The problem is the line `pthread_create(&x, NULL, d_q, NULL)`. It gives me `Error: Reference to non-static member must be called.`

I get rid of this problem by making pthread_t x `static`. But I dont want to do this because of 2 reasons:

1. Creation of a thread with a static function means only 1 copy of the function.
2. The thread is created in a constructor. I don't know what will happen if I create more than one objects of class C.

Can someone please give me a workaround?

Solved: Thanks for the help! 
Also, a very good advice is to **prefer std::thread over pthread for future users!**

Comment: Try using `std::thread` instead.

Comment: `std::int`? What's that?

Comment: Use `std::thread`. There are plenty examples on how to bind a non-static member function one of those.

Comment: I'll note that creating a thread in a constructor is generally a bad idea - if you throw an exception in the ctor, you'll automatically destroy the object, but the thread is still running and trying to use the object. If the object is created  in automatic scope (e.g. a local variable) you'll also run into destruction before the thread terminates unless you're careful to join it in the destructor. It's better to be explicit with a `start()` function or similar, in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your problem, you a pointer to a (non-static) member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function. Non-static member functions needs an instance of an object to be called on.

There are a couple of ways to solve this: If you insist on using POSIX thread functions then you could make a `static` wrapper function, pass the instance as an argument to the thread, and in the static wrapper function call the actual function using the object passed.

Another solution is to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), which will make it much easier:

```
class C
{
    std::thread thread_;
    ...
public:
    C() : thread_(&C::d_q, this) {}
    ...
    void d_q() { ... }
};
```

Comment: Okay, this posed another problem. Error: attempt to use a deleted function!

Comment: @VShreyas, this post may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25649639/36723

Comment: okay.d_q is defined as:
void d_q();
So, no arguments. can u help me now?

Comment: @VShreyas *What* function is deleted?